# A topology is coherent with the subspaces if and only if it is the final topology on the inclusion maps

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $\{X_\alpha\}$ is a family of subspaces whose union is $X$. Show that the topology of $X$ is coherent with the subspaces $\{X_\alpha\}$ if and only if it is the finest topology on $X$ for which all of the inclusion maps $i_\alpha: X_\alpha \hookrightarrow X$ are continuous.

The only if part is easy. However, I am struggling with the if direction. How can I show that if there exists a subset $U$ of $X$ for which $U \cap X_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$, but $U$ is not open in $\mathscr{T}$, the topology on $X$, then it is not the final topology for $i_\alpha$?

Comment: what does coherent mean here?

Comment: @GuidoA. It means $U \subset X$ is open in $X$ if and only if $U \cap X_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.

Comment: Are you talking about finest or final? If you mean the former, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3905281/291842). (The problem itself is poorly phrased, IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mathscr T$ is the finest topology for which the inclusion maps $i_{\alpha}$ are continuous. Let $U\subseteq X$ such that $U \cap X_{\alpha} \in \mathscr T$ for all
$\alpha.$ If $U$ is not open in $\mathscr T$ then by defining a new topology $\mathscr T\subseteq \mathscr T_1$ by adding $U$ to $\mathscr T$, we obtain a finer topology such that every $i_{\alpha}$ is continuous. This is a contradiction.

Comment: I thought about this argument, but to obtain the finer topology containing $U$, we need to add all the unions with $U$ and the finite intersections with $U$. So how can we guarantee that $i_\alpha$ will still be continuous?

Comment: $\mathscr T_1$ is the smallest topology that contains all the  sets in  $\mathscr T$ and $U$ so if $V\in \mathscr T$ then $i_{\alpha}^{-1}(U\cap V)=X_{\alpha}\cap V\cap U$ which is open in $X_{\alpha}$ ( in the subspace topology of $\mathscr T_1$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \{0,1\}$ be the Sierpisnki space (I will note $1$ for the 'open point'). Now, consider the indicator function of $U$ viewed as a map $\chi_U : X \to S$. Each restriction to $X_\alpha$ is continuous, as

$$
(\chi_U\iota_\alpha)^{-1}(1) = i_\alpha^{-1}(U) = U \cap X_\alpha
$$

is open in $X_\alpha$ by hypothesis. However, the set $U = \chi_U^{-1}(1)$ is not open and so $\chi_U$ is not continuous. This contradicts that the family of inclusions is final.

Another approach: define $\tau'$ as the topology generated by the subasis $\tau \cup \{U\}$ with $\tau$ the topology on $X$. This is a strictly finer topology as it contains $U$, and each inclusion $i_\alpha$ is continuous: we only need to check that preimages of subbasic open sets are open, and since $i_\alpha : X_\alpha \to (X,\tau)$ is continuous it suffices to observe that by our assumption

$$
i_\alpha^{-1}(U) = U \cap X_\alpha
$$

is open. Again, this is a contradiction.