# Coherence of topology and finest topology such that inclusion maps are continuous

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following problem from Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ be a collection such that $\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha=X$. Show that $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is coherent with $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ if and only if $\mathcal{T}$ is the finest topology such that $X_\alpha \hookrightarrow X$ is continuous for all $X_\alpha$.

I am having some trouble finishing the proof of the forward direction, in particular with proving that $\mathcal{T}$ is indeed the finest topology. My attempt is as follows:

Let $\mathcal{T}'$ be another topology such that $X_\alpha\hookrightarrow X$ is continuous. My first question here is that, for the inclusion map $\iota_\alpha:X_\alpha\to X$, is the topology on $X_\alpha$ is the subspace topology induced by $\mathcal{T}'$ and, further, is $\mathcal{T}'$ the topology on $X$? I will proceed as if those assumptions are true.

We want to show that $\mathcal{T}'\subseteq \mathcal{T}$. Let $U\in\mathcal{T}'$, since $\{X_{\alpha}\}$ is coherent with respect to $(X,\mathcal{T})$, it suffices to show that $U\cap X_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$, **where $X_\alpha$ has the subspace topology induced by $\mathcal{T}$**. Notice that
$$\iota_\alpha^{-1}(U) = U\cap X_\alpha,$$
which is open in $X_\alpha$ with respect to the **subspace topology on $X_\alpha$ induced by $\mathcal{T}'$**. I'm not sure how to connect the above concepts. That is, I am having trouble showing that if $U\cap X_\alpha$ is open with respect to the **subspace topology on $X_\alpha$ induced by $\mathcal{T}'$**, it is also open with respect to **subspace topology on $X_\alpha$ induced by $\mathcal{T}$**.

However, if we assume that, for the inclusion map $\iota_\alpha:X_\alpha\to X$, the topology on $X_\alpha$ is the subspace topology induced by $\mathcal{T}$, then the problem is resolved. I'm not quite sure which of these interpretations is correct, thanks!

Comment: You should give us the **definition** of "$(X,\mathcal{T})$ is coherent with the spaces $\{X_{\alpha}\}$".

Comment: $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is coherent with the family $\{X_\alpha\}$ if, for all $U\subseteq X$, the set $U$ is open in $X$ if and only if $U\cap X_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ for all $X_\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us begin with some notation: By $\mathcal T_\alpha$ we denote the given topology on $X_\alpha$. The set $X = \bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha$ does not yet have a topology, but we *define* the topology $\mathcal T$ coherent with the family $(\{X_\alpha,\mathcal T_\alpha) \}$  as the set all $U \subset X$ such that $U \cap X_\alpha \in  \mathcal T_\alpha$ or all $\alpha$. This topology *by definition* has the property that all  $\iota_\alpha : (X_\alpha, \mathcal T_\alpha) \hookrightarrow (X, \mathcal T)$ are continuous (simply because $\iota_\alpha^{-1}(U) = U \cap X_\alpha \in  \mathcal T_\alpha$ for $U \in \mathcal T$).

Let us emphasize that we start with a collection of *topological spaces $\{X_\alpha \}$*. In your question the topology on the set $X_\alpha$ is not named, here we *explicitly* give it the name $\mathcal T_\alpha$. Note that without a *given topology* on the set $X_\alpha$ it does not make any sense to define (as you did in your comment) that $(X, \mathcal T)$ is coherent with the family $\{X_\alpha\}$ if, for all $U \subset X$, the set $U$ is open in $X$ if and only if $U \cap X_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.

Now you consider any topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $X$ such that all $\iota_\alpha : (X_\alpha, \mathcal T_\alpha) \hookrightarrow (X, \mathcal T')$ are continuous. So yes, $\mathcal{T}'$ is the topology on $X$. This does **not** mean that the topology $\mathcal T_\alpha$ on $X_\alpha$ is the subspace topology induced by $\mathcal{T}'$. It only says that the original topology $\mathcal T_\alpha$ on $X_\alpha$ is finer than the subspace topology $\mathcal T'_\alpha = \{ U \cap X_\alpha \mid U \in \mathcal T'\}$ induced by $\mathcal T'$ on the set $X_\alpha$. This will be shown below.
In your proof you want to show that for $U \in \mathcal T'$ we have $U \cap X_\alpha \in  \mathcal T'_\alpha$. But this does not require a proof because $\mathcal T'_\alpha$ was *defined* as the subspace topology induced on $X_\alpha$ by $\mathcal{T}'$.

So let us give a correct proof of $\mathcal T' \subset \mathcal T$ which is also more or less obvious.

Consider $U \in \mathcal T'$. Then, because the $\iota_\alpha$ are assumed to be continuous, $U \cap X_\alpha = \iota_\alpha^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal T_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ and thus by definition of the coherent topology, we have $U \in \mathcal T$.

The argument in the preceding sentence also shows that $\mathcal T'_\alpha \subset \mathcal T_\alpha$, i.e. that $\mathcal T_\alpha$ is finer than  $\mathcal T'_\alpha$ (as claimed above).

Comment: Why is the original $\mathcal{T}_\alpha$ on $X_\alpha$ finer than the subspace topology $\mathcal{T}_{\alpha}'$ induced by $\mathcal{T}'$ on $X_\alpha$? Isn't that kinda assuming the result we want?

Comment: @varpi See my edit.

Comment: But you are still assuming $\mathcal{T}_\alpha$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}'_\alpha$, which is not stated in the coherence hypothesis...

Comment: @varpi I am not assuming it, but I prove it. The only assumption is that all $\iota_\alpha$ are continuous.

Comment: What are the $\iota_\alpha$'s continuous with respect to? The map is $\iota_\alpha:X_\alpha\to X$, but what is the topology on $X_\alpha$ at the start? Continuity doesn't make sense until you define a topology on $X_\alpha$

Comment: @varpi I am sorry, I cannot explain it better than in my answer. I offer you to delete my answer which gives you the chance that somebody else gives a better answer.

Comment: @varpi I made a final edit. If you wish deletion of my answer, let me know.

Comment: Ironically, the actual difficult part of the proof is not the proof itself, but the "correct" interpretation of the problem. Your interpretation is the one that actually makes sense.